# Exact seconds in recording video with AVCaptureSession (ObjC / Swift)

Tags: objective-c, swift, avcapturesession

I am recording a video of a pre-determined length of time given by a variable, for example, `var recordingTime: Double = 4.0`.

I trigger the recording as usual:

```
movieFileOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: outputFilePath), recordingDelegate: self)
```

and then set a timer that stops recording after the recording time in `func capture ...`:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + self.recordingTime) {
  captureOutput.stopRecording()
}
```

So you would assume that it would create a video that is exactly 4 seconds, right? Well the video duration comes out to `4.47` and then oddly if I make `var recordingTime: Double = 8.0`, then the video duration becomes `8.87`? What the heck is going on here?

Comment: Try to make the recordingTime = 3.53. What happens then?

Comment: @maximilian_cs I have done something like this to account for the time lag and it creates a video that is near 4 seconds (like 4.03) but just off. Furthermore, it really screwed things up as the recordingTime duration increases and becomes less and less accurate :(

Comment: You could try using something like: var activeVideoMinFrameDuration: CMTime (The currently active minimum frame duration) or var activeVideoMaxFrameDuration: CMTime (The currently active maximum frame duration)

Comment: @maximilian_cs Just tried it as per Apple documentation and it seemed to have no effect on the time. It set the frame rate as indicated but final duration was still 4.47